# Ajax Refresh Removing Newly Added Class

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a shoutbox that automatically refreshes every x seconds with:

```
var refreshIntervalId = null;
var ref = $.cookie('refresh');

    // refresh the shoutbox every x seconds (x is defined by the cookie)
    refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function () {
        shoutbox.load('ajax.php');
    }, ref);
```

I've added an option to remove the alternating row colours by adding another class with:

```
$('.row:nth-child(odd)').addClass('alt');
```

The problem is that whenever the refresh occurs, the new class that was added is removed.

Is there a way of stopping the class from being removed?

**EDIT**: Forgot to add that if a cookie is present then the class is added, if it isn't present, the class is removed.

**RESOLVED**: I had to add the following to ajax.php:

```
if ($.cookie('alt') === 'No') {
    $('.row:nth-child(odd)').addClass('alt');
}

if ($.cookie('alt') === 'Yes') {
    $('.row:nth-child(odd)').removeClass('alt');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to add the script to ajax.php.